# Auto-Starting Seafile Server 12.04 (Server Edition)

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, webapps, init

I'm having trouble getting Seafile to auto-start upon boot-up.

here's what I've done so far:

Created ~/lovette/seafile-control-script.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/seafile
#
# Start/Stop/Restart seafile and seahub

seafileDir=/home/lovette/
currentRelease=seafile-server-2.0.4

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
echo "$1 Seahub "
$seafileDir/$currentRelease/seahub.sh $1
echo "$1 Seafile "
$seafileDir/$currentRelease/seafile.sh $1

exit 0
```

Made it executable:

```
chmod 750 seafile-control-script.sh
```

Created another file in /etc/init.d/seafile

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd="sudo bash -c 'cd ~/lovette;./seafile-control-script.sh $1'" 
su - colter -c "$cmd"
```

Also, made it executable:

```
sudo chmod 750 /etc/init.d/seafile
```

Turned it into a service:

```
: cd /etc/init.d
: sudo update-rc.d seafile defaults
```

The switches (start/stop) work great and if I run them once the system boots, Seafile has no issues starting up. However, the system simply wont do it automatically (ie. If I reboot, Seafile is not started.)

I've tried to review the way init script are written for other programs and there doesn't seem to be any discrepancies with the process here and that coupled with the start/stop working correctly, I'm at a loss as to why Ubuntu wouldn't be successful at getting it to start on it's own.

Could it possibly be because a dependency it needs is trying to start after this script is ran (MySQL for example), can I somehow reorder the start-up list if that is the case?

Any ideas would be helpful. I apologize if this is elementary, I'm a novice right now.

Comment: I feel as though I should give credit to the guide I followed, so here is the [link](http://www.reflections.co.nz/wordpress/?p=267).

Comment: Output when running update-rc again:                              colter@lovette-server:~$ sudo update-rc.d seafile defaults
    update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/seafile missing LSB information
    update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
    System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/seafile already exist.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is getting old now.. but did you check the seafile github?

https://github.com/haiwen/seafile/wiki/Start-seafile-server-at-system-bootup

Comment: Welcome to  Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include explanation how to solve issue, and provide the link for reference.