# How to auto start SeaFile Client?

Tags: startup-applications

SeaFile Client automatically starts in Windows but not is Ubuntu
How to add seafile entry into startup application so that it always starts automatically?

Comment: This might help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/382765/auto-starting-seafile-server-12-04-server-edition

Comment: @vembutech that's for the server, not the end user client

Answer (score 2):

To start Seafile when you login to KDE: Launch autostart

Select 'desktop file' then 'add program' on right.

Type 'seafile-applet' in the search box and press OK.

Press OK to confirm the addition

Answer (score 2):

You can also use GNOME Tweaks. You can install it with:

`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

Tweaks has a *Startup Applications* menu entry, where you can search for installed applications and add them to the list of startup applications.

[IMG of Tweaks Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0f4W.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Gnome desktop and the launch via the seafile destop file would not work. What worked for me: I opened the seafile.desktop (/usr/share/applications) file in an editor and checked out the exec line (seafile-applet). I tested to start seafile with typing 'seafile-applet' in the terminal, which worked fine. I then added this line in the command field of the dialog of the startup application. 
So basically very similar to the KDE version as described above.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, a symlink in ~/.config/autostart works fine:

```
cd ~/.config/autostart/
ln -s /usr/share/applications/seafile.desktop
```

Comment: Using this solution, Seafile also shows up in the "Startup Applications" GUI.